# Fetch real time stock data using Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit

I'm trying to build a stock app which the prices of each row (stock) are changing real time. I'm currently using Retrofit library for making all the API calls in my app. What's the best way to achieve the real time data loading? I notice Retrofit has @streaming feature, not sure if it's suitable. I'm thinking to periodically call the api and refresh the adapter but this is probably too intensive for the app? Please advise

Comment: Maybe this isn't a solution, but it might help :: https://iextrading.com/developer/

Comment: Hi @Barns, I'm trying IEX out, I have a page displaying some stocks via this API https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#batch-requests, wha's the best way to periodically refresh the price data?

Comment: I have not tried IEX, but when I skimmed the website I mistakenly read RealTime as RealTime Database--sorry. But, in the past, when I needed data to be updated on a regular basis I would set a timer that would query my API in a set time interval (a time interval that matches the time frame in which the data remains "relevant"). Then I would provide the user a settings option where they can change that time interval to match their needs (and data package) or allow them to turn off the update function in order to initiate updates manually. Good Luck!